# Connect PC with network and a direct connection to a server

Tags: linux, networking, routing, linux-networking

I have a server which is connected with a 1Gbit connection to the whole network. Recently I have bought two 10gbit network cards.
I would like to Connect the server with the PC directly (using the 10gbit cards) and maintain the connection to the rest of the network on both machines.

What do I need to configure and how?
I'm new to this networking stuff.

Thanks in advanced.

EDIT: The server runs Linux and the PC is dualbooting Windows and Linux but primary Linux.

---

ASCII draft:

```
PC---------------------------Switch----------------Remaining network

   *                          -

       *                  -

           *         -

             Server

- =  1 gbit
* = 10 gbit
```

Comment: the configuration is probably OS dependent, but you didn't state what are the OS involved. In the case of all Linux systems, this questions could be solved like my answer in that Q/A: https://serverfault.com/questions/1018400/sharing-same-ip-across-two-nics-to-route-one-ip-over-dedicated-nic . There are probably multiple ways to achieve the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straightforward routing will achieve this.

If your LAN was 10.20.30.0/24 and the PC had 10.20.30.40 on its 1 Gbit link, then your 10 Gbit card would be configured with some other network range.

The Server could have 10.99.99.1/24  and your PC would have 10.99.99.99 /24   There would be no default gateway on this second link.

PC would send all traffic out its 1Gbit port, either directly or via the configured internet gateway.

Server would have no knowledge of anything except 10.99.99.xx  As a side effect of this, Server would have no access to any other hosts ever, for updates.  While it might be possible to use PC as a gateway, that's getting convoluted.

If you want Server to have normal network access, consider using a separate 1 Gbit card for LAN access, and therefore internet access.  Server and PC would have to have hosts overrides so their hostnames return the private interconnect IP addresses rather than the LAN addressing.

Long term, this will set you up for the day you can get a 10 Gbit-capable switch.

Comment: I've deliberately left this answer to be OS agnostic.